# islice from right-hand side

Tags: python, slice, python-itertools, deque

For lists one can use slicing `my_list[-10:]` to get the last (up to) `10` elements

I want to do the same with `itertools.islice`. In this case I have a `collections.deque`.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this than the following?

```
from collections import deque
import itertools
my_deque = deque()
my_list = list()
for i in range(100):
    my_deque.append(i)
    my_list.append(i)
```

And then we do the slicing:

```
start = max(0, len(my_deque) - 10)
for i in list(itertools.islice(my_deque, start, None)):
    pass
```

### My timings:

**deque:** 1000000 loops, best of `3: 962 ns` per loop

**list slicing:** 10000000 loops, best of `3: 95.9 ns` per loop

Comment: Show the full, exact, complete, runnable code to get those `timeit` results.

Comment: `itertools` is designed for working with arbitrary, possibly infinite, iterators. An infinite iterator doesn't have a "last" 10 items. Also, for an arbitrary iterator, the *only* way to get an item is to call its `next` method to get a single item; more efficient methods simply don't exist.

Comment: About `for i in list(itertools.islice(my_deque, start, None)):` the conversion into a list is useless and may use memory for nothing.

Comment: Why not simply using `deque.rotate()` then yield values till your desired range ?

Comment: @chepner unless the iterator has a `__reversed__` method i guess

Comment: @Chris_Rands I don't think there's any iterator that has a `__reversed__` method, only some containers have that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out there's no way to slice a `collections.deque`. But it supports `rotation` which could be used in this case:

```
last_n = 10
my_deque.rotate(last_n)
for i in itertools.islice(my_deque, last_n):
    pass
```

The problem with `itertools.islice` in this case is that it needs to iterate over all elements until it reaches the `stop`. That's because it needs to work with iterators in general not only with random-access-containers like `list`s and `deque`s. So in your case the `islice` really had to iterate over all elements in the `deque`. With `rotate` and then `islice` it only has to iterate over 10 elements.

As for timings, it's hard to know what you compared but using this setup:

```
from collections import deque
import itertools
my_deque = deque(range(10000))
my_list = list(range(10000))
```

I get the following timings:

```
%%timeit

my_deque.rotate(10)
for i in itertools.islice(my_deque, 10):
    pass
my_deque.rotate(-10)  # so the next timing operates on the orginal deque again
```

> 2.76 µs ± 41.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%%timeit

start = max(0, len(my_deque) - 10)
for i in itertools.islice(my_deque, start, None):
    pass
```

> 136 µs ± 8.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

```
%%timeit

start = max(0, len(my_list) - 10)
for i in itertools.islice(my_list, start, None):
    pass
```

> 119 µs ± 1.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

```
%timeit my_list[-10:]
```

> 434 ns ± 12.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

So it can't beat list slicing (still ~5 times slower) but it's definitely much faster (~50 times) than using your `islice` approaches.